# Optimizing recursive backtrack search algorithm in Skyscraper puzzle

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, python-3.x

I'm trying to solve [a skyscraper puzzle](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5679d5a3f2272011d700000d) for 6x6 boards using constraint programming and then backtracking. My solution works but is too slow, for certain cases, it takes up to 2 seconds and I was wondering how I could reduce this.

Here is the structure of my algorithm:

1. Create board of N size with each element having integers from 1 to 6 denoting all the possibilities
   ie: `[[[1,2,3,4,5,6] , [1,2,3,4,5,6,] , [1,2,3,4,5,6]]]`  etc
2. Using the clues given, fill out values which I am certain of.
   ie: If clue is 1, then closest element is 6 , if clue is 6 then the row is [1,2,3,4,5,6]
3. Cross out possibilities if the value is already in column or row
4. If inside one row (or column) a list of possibilities has a value that none of the other have, then it becomes that number:
   ie: `[[1,2,3,4,5,6] , [1,2,3,4,5] , [1,2,3,4,5]]` becomes ``` [ 6 , [1,2,3,4,5] , [1,2,3,4,5]]

Finally, I have my backtracking algorithm, which according to Pycharm takes 98% of the time of execution:

````py
def search(zero, clues, searchBoard):
 #zeros is a deepcopy of searchboard but with possibilities replaces with 0s ; search board is the board after being processed by first 4 steps
    find = empty(zero)  # Checks for zeroes in a duplicate list
    findLeast = full(searchBoard)  # Checks for elements that have more than one possibility
    if not find:
        return True
    else:
        row, col = findLeast  # Fetches the index of the element with least amount of possibilities
    val = searchBoard[row][col]
    for i in val:  # loops through those possibilties
        if is_valid_solution(zero, clues, 6, i, (row, col)):
            zero[row][col] = i  # If the possibilitie works, insert it
            searchBoard[row][col] = i
            if search(zero, clues,
                      searchBoard):  # recursively do this (backtrack) until no more empty elements in the zeroes duplicate list
                return True
            zero[row][col] = 0  # else: reset, try again for different values
            searchBoard[row][col] = val
    return False

def is_valid_solution(board, clues, n, num, pos):
    row = [num if i == pos[1] else board[pos[0]][i] for i in range(6)]
    col = [num if i == pos[0] else board[i][pos[1]] for i in range(6)]


    if row.count(num) > 1:
        return False
    if col.count(num) > 1:
        return False

    clue = clues[pos[1]]
    if clue != 0 and clue not in flatten(col):
        return False

    clue = clues[pos[0] + 6]
    if clue != 0 and clue not in flatten(row[::-1]):
        return False

    clue = clues[::-1][pos[1] + 6]
    if clue != 0 and clue not in flatten(col[::-1]):
        return False

    clue = clues[::-1][pos[0]]
    if clue != 0 and clue not in flatten(row):
        return False
    return True

def verifyDistance(cell):
    visible = 0
    max = 0
    for i in range(len(cell)):
        if cell[i] > max:
            visible += 1
            max = cell[i]
    return visible


def flatten(incompleted_row):
    possible_rows = []
    d = list({1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} - set([x for x in incompleted_row if x != 0]))
    for perm in permutations(d):
        row = incompleted_row.copy()
        for e in perm:
            row[row.index(0)] = e
        possible_rows.append(row)
    possible_clues = set()
    for r in possible_rows:
        possible_clues.add(verifyDistance(r))
    return list(possible_clues)


def empty(puzzle):
    if 0 in chain.from_iterable(puzzle):
        return True
    return None

def full(puzzle):
    pos = []

    for i in range(len(puzzle)):  # loop through the rows of the puzzle
        try:
            pos.append([(i, puzzle[i].index(min((x for x in puzzle[i] if isinstance(x, list)), key=len))), puzzle[i]])
            # append the tuple (i , j) where i is the row number and j the column number, and the smallest list of possibilities in each row
        except ValueError:
            i += 1

    try:
        champion, champion_len = pos[0][0], len(pos[0][1])  # unpack the pos list into the tuple, and the possibilties
    except IndexError:
        return None
    for t, sl in pos:
        if len(sl) < champion_len:
            champion, champion_len = t, len(sl)  # look for the smallest number of possibilities and return their index
    return champion
```
````

Comment: Please add a description of the skyscraper puzzle.

Comment: @RootTwo , fixed.